# Ubuntu manual upgrader for 19.04 still showing development version for 19.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, 18.10, 19.04

I am attempting to upgrade Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04 (I am writing this on the release date for 19.04) and my graphical update manager is not finding the release.  (I am set to the main update server)  I used "update-manager -d" and the release that popped up was listed as the development release.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 19.04 is uploaded to the main site (for download by mirrors) prior to official release; if bugs are discovered and a new 'spin' is made, and the uploaded ISO is just overwritten  (*so ISO may change at this stage even if unlikely*).

The official notice is made when all sign-offs are made, for Ubuntu 19.04 this notice is https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2019-April/004753.html  (the ISO won't change from this point; if a new change is required it'll have a new designation like 17.10.1)

However even on release, upgrades may not be switched on for a *day or 3*. They will only be turned on when release team have are happy that no serious undiscovered upgrade bug has been found. Only when Disco (Ubuntu 19.04) is added to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release will normal upgrades start to work (without the -d *development* option).

*Last paragraph is largely from a #ubuntu-discuss discussion, and source is Rik Mills (acheronuk)*

Answer (score 0):

I just followed these instructions and was able to update.  I had to go through the terminal not software store.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-19-04-disco-dingo

Comment: Also, you may want to wait a few weeks as suggested, I am experiencing some bugs with audio driver and had apps randomly uninstalled, also desktop icons will be gone after update and have to manually enable them.